# want to convert timestamp to date and filter data month wise in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, timestamp

i have date as a timestamp in database and i want to convert timestamp into date while fetching data from database, after that want to filter data according to current month wise.

I'm new laravel

Comment: Try something, post some code... we can help then...

Answer (score 0):

In Your eloquent model add this property [(more info here)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators):

```
protected $dates = ['column_name'];
```

It will be automatically wrap in `Carbon`

For Example

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ExampleModel extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['start_date', 'end_date'];
}
```

For filter data by month use

```
ExampleModel::whereMonth('start_date', '12')->get();
```